# Did Poland and Hungary withdraw from (i.e. fully denounce) the Convention on Early Notification of a Nuclear Accident?

Tags: nuclear-energy, poland, hungary

Wikipedia says so ([since 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Convention_on_Early_Notification_of_a_Nuclear_Accident&oldid=573430222)), and there's [a list](https://www-legacy.iaea.org/Publications/Documents/Conventions/cenna_status.pdf) on IAEA website that seemingly backs that up... but it's not wholly clear what the list actually means (image/table cropped to Poland.)

> [image]

Wikipedia's write-up/interpretation:

> The states that have ratified the Convention but have since denounced it and withdrawn from the agreement are Bulgaria, Hungary, Mongolia, and Poland.

On the other hand, Poland's gov't [website](https://www.gov.pl/web/paa-en/International-Law) says they are (still) in...

> The PAA bears responsibility for the performance by Poland as the contracting party of below treaties, conventions and international agreements: [...]
>
> Convention on Early Notification of a Nuclear Accident, done at Vienna on 26 September 1986 (Date of ratification by Poland: 24.2.1988)

Image cropped to remote lots of other treaties:

> [image]

So, did Poland really withdraw, i.e. fully denounce the [Convention on Early Notification of a Nuclear Accident](https://www.iaea.org/topics/nuclear-safety-conventions/convention-early-notification-nuclear-accident)? (And if so, when?)

Hungary's website is less clear on dates, but also [says](https://www.oah.hu/web/v3/haeaportal.nsf/web?openagent&menu=03&submenu=3_6):

> Hungary is a contracting party to the following international conventions on the peaceful, safe and secured use of atomic energy: [...]
>
> Convention on Early Notification of a Nuclear Accident
> (ENC)

So the Wikipedia claim seems in doubt on that as well.

Comment: [treaties.un.org](https://treaties.un.org/Pages/showActionDetails.aspx?objid=08000002800cf68e&clang=_en) shows Poland as having made a *withdrawal of reservation made upon ratification* circa 1997.  I think that would be strengthening their agreement to the treaty, not denouncing it.  Perhaps this was abbreviated in the IAEA table and then misinterpreted by the Wikipedia editor.

Comment: @NateEldredge: yeah, I found that at about the same time. Go ahead, write an answer. There is actually [a table](https://treaties.un.org/pages/showDetails.aspx?objid=08000002800cf3c9) on UN's website, which makes it more clear. Hungary has 3 entries there (signature, ratification, withdrawal *of reservation*).

Comment: I've updated the Wikipedia page based on the conclusion reached here.

Comment: I think you mean "renounce" (to announce that one will no longer take part) rather than "denounce" (to strongly criticize in public). I see you copied this error from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think the reference to withdrawal may have been a mistake.

[treaties.un.org](https://treaties.un.org/pages/showDetails.aspx?objid=08000002800cf3c9) has a status table for this treaty.  They show that Poland [ratified the treaty in 1988](https://treaties.un.org/Pages/showActionDetails.aspx?objid=08000002800cf687&clang=_en) but with the following **reservation**:

> The Polish People's Republic does not consider itself bound by the provisions of paragraph 2 of article 11 of the Convention.

This paragraph stated that parties to the treaty agreed to have disputes arbitrated by the International Court of Justice.  Paragraph 3 explicitly allowed parties to make such declarations, essentially "opting out" of that arbitration process.

In 1997, Poland [withdrew this reservation](https://treaties.un.org/Pages/showActionDetails.aspx?objid=08000002800cf68e&clang=_en), so that they now agree to the entire treaty, including the ICJ arbitration clause.  I think this may account for the "withdraw" in the IAEA table, which may then have been misinterpreted by the Wikipedia editors as meaning denunciation.

Answer (score 17):

Same thing with Hungary actually; there's a [UN table](https://treaties.un.org/pages/showDetails.aspx?objid=08000002800cf3c9) that instead of checkboxes (like IAEA) has a row entries for each event.

[image]

Hungary & Poland like many other countries from the Eastern block (at the time), including Russia, signed the treaty with a reservation on a clause about arbitration at ICJ. Some countries, like Hungary, later withdrew this reservation. That the latter event happened after the Berlin wall fell is probably not too coincidental.